# Where should I store Vault's Unseal Key and Root Token?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Where should I store the Unseal Key and Root Token for HashiCorp Vault?

The Vault will be used by various members on the team.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In best-practice usage, you wouldn't be storing a root token - once done with it, [it should be revoked](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/tokens.html#root-tokens).

> Root tokens are useful in development but should be extremely
>   carefully guarded in production. 
>   In fact, the Vault team recommends
>   that root tokens are only used for just enough initial setup (usually,
>   setting up auth methods and policies necessary to allow administrators
>   to acquire more limited tokens) or in emergencies, and are revoked
>   immediately after they are no longer needed.
>
> If a new root token is
>   needed, the operator generate-root command and associated API endpoint
>   can be used to generate one on-the-fly.

Unseal keys should be distributed amongst trusted people, with nobody having access to more than one of them.

This then requires more than one person to restart vault or to gain root access to it.

The documentation doesn't suggest any good hiding places for the individual unseal keys that I could find - I'd suggest wherever you normally store passwords, ie a password manager.

For day-to-day usage, users can log in using the [user/pass](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/userpass.html) or [ldap](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/ldap.html) auth backends.

Comment: // , As to where to store the all-important Unseal Keys, I, personally, use https://keepassxc.org, because it's open source and uses AES-256. I tend to recommend it, along with GPG encryption to a paper back-up, where a default personal password manager doesn't exist for a client.